# Scanner problems. Split problems. Can't find symbol - java

Tags: java

This is what I got returned and I cannot figure out what error: cannot find symbol

```
    C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestFile.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                            ^
      symbol:   class Scanner
      location: class TestFile
    C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestFile.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                                             ^
      symbol:   class Scanner
      location: class TestFile
    C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TestFile.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
                            String[] tabs = prep.Split(" ");
                                                ^
      symbol:   method Split(String)
      location: variable prep of type String
    3 errors
```

This is my code.

```
public class TestFile {

    String[] preps = {
        "about", "above", "across", "after", "against",
        "along", "among", "around", "at", "before",
        "behind", "below", "beneath", "beside", "between",
        "by", "concerning", "down", "during", "except",
        "for", "from", "in", "inside", "into",
        "like", "near", "of", "onto", "out",
        "over", "through", "to", "toward", "under",
        "up", "upon", "with", "within", "without"
    };

    String[] errorpreps = {
        "will", "would", "shall", "should", "can",
        "could", "may", "might", "must", 
    };

    String[] question = {
    };


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestFile f = new TestFile();

        f.generatecode("hi");

    };

    public String generatecode(String code){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inp = sc.nextString();

        String prep = "";

        for (int i=0; i<preps.length+1; i++){ //retuns all inputed things into prep

            prep = preps + preps[i] + " ";

        }

        String[] tabs = prep.Split(" "); //splits the inputed thing and puts it into tab

        for (int f=1; f<tabs.length+1; f++){
            String prox = tabs[f];

            if(prox.contains(".")){
                prep = "Found a .!";
            } else if(prox.contains("?")){
                prep = "Found a ?!";
            } else if(prox.contains("!")){
                prep = "Found a !!";
            } else if(prox.contains(",")){
                prep = "Found a ,!";
            }
        }

        return prep;

    }

    public String printcode(String code){


        return "";

    }

}
```

Now the thing is I do not know much about Scanner. I didn't import anything. I know some about the split method. I cannot figure out why my syntax is not right. I believe it's correct syntax going off of other examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Immeditaly, `String#split` is lower case, so `prep.Split(" ")` should be `prep.split(" ")`

Comment: @Abi: Close -- it's import with a lower case I.

Comment: Speling and CaSe MatTer!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Use `**` around the word to make it **bolder** (`**bolder**`) :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - yes, actually that was meant to be a statement.anyway edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems:

- You don't import the Scanner class; if you don't understand why you need to, see [this](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2008/06/import-statements.html). Put this at the beginning of your code:

  `import java.util.Scanner;`
- `String.split()` is lowercase.

  You write:  `String[] tabs = prep.Split(" ");`
  Should be:  `String[] tabs = prep.split(" ");`